# ActiveAdmin has_many relationship does not save new records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have the relation ContentRelease has_many pages. The following activeadmin registered model lets me edit properties of a page inside the content_release, but not create new pages for the content release. There is no error, I get a success message, but a new page is not saved. What am I doing wrong?

```
ActiveAdmin.register ContentRelease do

  form do |f|
    f.actions

    f.inputs "Details" do
      f.input :active_at
    end

    f.inputs "Pages", :class => 'pages-list' do
      f.has_many :pages do |page|

        page.inputs "Associated Look" do
          page.input :title
          page.input :content_release, :as => :select, :collection => ContentRelease.list
          page.input :look, :as => :select, :collection => Look.current
          page.input :share_url
        end

      end
    end

    f.inputs "Looks", :class => 'looks-list' do
      f.has_many :looks do |look|
        look.inputs do
          look.input :title
        end
      end
    end

    f.actions


  end
```

Comment: What is the server output when this happens? Any warnings about mass-assignment?

Comment: Have you figured the answer to this issue? I have the same problem.